# How to change the token expiry time after page refresh in angular?

Tags: token, reload, angular17

After login I am generating a token and I am saving that in storage session. The expiry time of the token is 8 minutes and everything is fine. The problem I am having is, when I upload a photo for example the page is refreshed and the token is still expiring exactly after 8 minutes but what I want is when refreshed I want to reset the token expiry time back to 8 minutes or generate a new token. How to do that?

in login I am generating token in API:

```
loginRes.Token = CreateJWT(user);

private string CreateJWT(User user)
    {
        var secretKey = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Key").Value;
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));

        var claims = new Claim[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString())
        };

        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                                key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor{
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(8),
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

where it says `Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(8),`

now in in frontend I have a page to upload photos and when I do the page is refreshed to show the uploaded photos

```
   initializeFileUploader()
  {
      this.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: this.baseUrl + '/familydocuments/add/photo/' + this.thefolder,
        authToken: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
        isHTML5: true,
        removeAfterUpload: true,
        autoUpload: true,
        maxFileSize: this.maxAllowedFileSize

      });

      this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
        file.withCredentials = false;
      };

      this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item,respose,status, header) => 
      {
          if (respose)
          {
              const photo = JSON.stringify(respose);
              const photos = JSON.parse(photo);
              this.allPhotos.push(photos);
          }

        // setTimeout(()=>
        // {
        //   window.location.reload();
        //   this.router.navigate(["familydocuments"])
        // }, 15000);
      };
  }

  );
```

either I need to generate new token or show the photo without reloading the page, How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you refresh your page and your application is reloaded you need to check few things:

- Do you have token available in the session storage.
- Is this token is not expired
- Is this token was issued to your user accoung or for other users?

If 'yes' to all then use the token from the session storage for your http transactions.

2. Refresh your token when it's close to expiration. When you receiev or read the token from the session storage, then you need to run some job based on your expiration time to send new request to your API and get new token. Some people simply run `setTimeout` with 1 minute before token expiration. When you received new token, then update in other places (session storage, etc.)

Simply saying, every time when you need to save new token or restore the token you need to run a function that calculates the expiration time and sets a timer to refresh the token. Example below:

`someservice.ts`

```
...
public yourLogin() {
  // your logic
  ...
  // start the timer
  refreshToken();
}

public restoreToken() {
  // your logic to restore from the sessions storage
  ...
  // start the timer
  refreshToken();
}

public logout() {
  ...
  // clear leftovers
  clearTokenTimer();
}

private refreshToken() {
    const myToken = jwt_decode<TokenDataModel>(token);
    // example calculate token
    const tokenTimeout = (myToken.exp * 1000 ) - Date.now() - 60000; // where 60000 - 1 min. timeout will be set to execute token refresh logic 1 min before timeout expiration
    // Initialize token refresh timer
    this.yourTokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      // refresh token
      ...
      // save token
      ...
    }, tokenTimeout );
}

private clearTokenTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.yourTokenTimer);
}
...
```

Your API side will be next way:

```
public class YourLoginController
{
  // login
  ...

  // refresh token
  [HttpGet("myrefreshtoken")]
  [Authorize]
  public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshMyToken()
  {
     // add try catch and validation as needed
     // where MyTokenDto custom data model with string Token and other prop based on your needs
     MyTokenDto newRefreshedToken = await yourUserTokenService.GetNewTokenAsync(HttpContext.User.Claims);
     return Ok(newRefreshedToken);
  }
}
```

Comment: how to check for the expiry? where it says Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(8), how to get that from token as I am returning return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

Comment: You can use ```const myToken = jwt_decode<TokenDataModel>(token);``` from ```import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";```. And then use ```myToken.exp``` to get the expiration information. You only need to specify TokenDataModel as interface and populate fields that you need.

Comment: For extending the expiration time you need to send you current token to your API and API will add new expiration date to the token and return it back to the front-end.

Comment: I am getting error for "TokenDataModel"

Comment: do you have an example how to send the token to api to extend the time then send back to frontend?

Comment: I will update the answer soon.

Comment: I was able to save the exp in storage: "tokenexpiry 1711569329"

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Jivopis I will try it tomorrow and let you know if I needed some help.

Comment: when you say in api: await yourUserTokenService, this service is in the backend or frontend?

Comment: yes, you would need to reissue a token with extended time from backend side.

Comment: just a question, what is the difference between refreshing token and looking if the user is idle?

Comment: idle usually done for auto logout. When user works his token still can be expired due to some other actions, and you don't want to send an expired token and got 401/403 message just by bad timing.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer and I will workout the solution with your guidance and tips above. I will open new post if I found any difficulties with the new code I am making.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257292/discussion-between-taleen-wahdan-and-jivopis).